# cakephp: question about caching cakephp

Tags: cakephp, caching

i use  `var $cacheAction = '1 hour';` 
cakephp create file `xxx_view_1245.php` in `cache/views/` , it cached.
but if i use

```
var $cacheAction = array(
          'view/' => '1 hour'
 );
```

cakephp dont cache, i dont know why , please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I use var

```
$cacheAction = array(
          'view' => '1 hour',
          'index'=>'1 hour'
 );
```

then it'll cache. WTF documentation: 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1380/Caching-in-the-Controller.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar issue in CakePHP 1.2. I believe it is safe to assume you are using CakePHP 1.3 since you linked to the 1.3 manual. It briefly (and almost cryptically) mentions to **"Remember to use your routes in the $cacheAction if you have any."**

So now I ask, are you hitting the page via a route defined and is that when it does not work?